# How can I determine the correct hex address for a laptop fan control?

Tags: fan

I have an HP Envy X360 (Model eu0043dx) with an AMD Ryzen 5000 series CPU. I have installed NBFC which is a fan control program. I need to configure NBFC with the correct fan control address for the read and write registers.

I have researched HP and AMD web sites looking to see if I can find the technical documents that define these. No luck!

Here is a sample configuration file for NBFC.

```
<FanConfiguration>
    <ReadRegister>149</ReadRegister>
    <WriteRegister>148</WriteRegister>
    <MinSpeedValue>174</MinSpeedValue>  
    <MaxSpeedValue>67</MaxSpeedValue> 
    <IndependentReadMinMaxValues>false</IndependentReadMinMaxValues>
    <MinSpeedValueRead>0</MinSpeedValueRead> 
    <MaxSpeedValueRead>0</MaxSpeedValueRead> 
    <ResetRequired>false</ResetRequired>
    <FanSpeedResetValue>255</FanSpeedResetValue>
    <FanDisplayName>CPU fan</FanDisplayName>
```

Any ideas on what the values might be or where I can find them.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/Analyze-your-notebook%27s-DSDT) is how you would figure it out, and I do me you, since it requires the code to be ran on your hardware

Comment: Great!  Thanks Ramhound!